# How to display Chatter feed using a VF Page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, chatter

I have an existing VF page in which I'm trying to add Chatter feed using the standerd tag of chatter:feed/
While doing so it's showing me an error saying **Chatter:feed cannot be nested inside forms tag** (My VF is using apex:form), I need to put the chatter inside the apex:form. How can this be achieved.
What I'm trying to do is:

[image]

Comment: You can't put it inside the form, so it must be outside the form. Why do you need it inside the form?

Comment: I've an existing page with all headers and footers everything customized, I want to show up the feed only when the user joins any group. That's why I need it inside, otherwise it's messing up my entire styling

Comment: you can do that logic outside form tag as well.

Comment: Could you tell me how? As i mentioned when doing so It's messing up my styling